# Java generic type : how to pass the right class type properly?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I have an abstract class like this :

```
public abstract class AnimalService<T extends Animal> {
   ...
   public T callAPI() {
     // here the Class<T> can be Fish.class or Salmon.class or any child class type of Animal
     return restTemplate.getForObject(url, Class<T>, params); 
   }
}
```

and a child class :

```
public class FishService<T extends Fish> extends AnimalService<Fish> {
   ...
}
```

and a grandchild class:

```
public class SalmonService extends FishAnimalService<Salmon> {
   ...
}
```

I think there is a design problem of this heritage. But how can I achieve that when I call `callAPI()` (in either `FishService` or `SalmonService`), I am able to pass the exact **class type** (e.g. `Fish.class` or `Salmon.class`) in which I call ?

Comment: Small correction: Your second class should be `public class FishService<T extends Fish> extends AnimalService<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is adding an abstract method that is overridden in the subclass to return the right class type:

```
public abstract class AnimalService<T extends Animal> {
   public T callAPI() {
     return restTemplate.getForObject(url, getAnimalClass(), params); 
   }
   abstract Class<T> getAnimalClass();
}

public class SalmonService extends FishAnimalService<Salmon> {
   Class<Salmon> getAnimalClass() {
      return Salmon.class;
   }
}
```

Another option is introducing an instance variable.

```
abstract class AnimalService<T extends Animal> {
   private Class<T> animalClass;

   protected AnimalService(Class<T> animalClass) {
      this.animalClass = animalClass;
   }

   public T callAPI() {
     return restTemplate.getForObject(url, animalClass, params); 
   }
}

public class FishService<T extends Fish> extends AnimalService<Fish> {
   protected FishService(Class<T> fishClass) {
      super(fishClass);
   }
}


public class SalmonService extends FishAnimalService<Salmon> {
   public SalmonService() {
      super(Salmon.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: Another option is obtaining the class from the generic superclass: `new AnimalService<Salmon>() {}`, then some reflection magick inside the constructor (as is done for type tokens in various libraries e.g. Guice).